# Access vba SQL delete query now stalls and never executes after working for months

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an access database which has tables linked to it from another access database to hold the data.  Daily a lab manager runs a process through a button click which transfers data from this database to a MS SQL Server database and then deletes the data from the Access database.  I have inherited these databases and do not have the time or the power to change database structure and we will be replacing the access databases completely with a new LIMS which we are in the process of purchasing and implementing over the next year.

My issue is that one of the DELETE sql queries has stopped executing.  Whenever I execute this query the database just hangs up (have let it go as long as 20 minutes) until I pull up the task manager and kill the application.  I have tried taking the SQL query out of the VBA environment and running it through a MS Access query and I get the same thing.  So basically it worked for a very long time (sense August of last year) and now it has stopped working.

Here is the SQL command for the Delete statement:

```
strSQL = "DELETE [TableName].* " _
    & "FROM [TableName] " _
    & "WHERE [TableName].[Run ID] NOT IN (SELECT [Run ID] FROM [SecondTableName] " _
    & "WHERE [Run ID] IS NOT NULL)"
```

Then that sql string is executed through a function in VBA.  We use that function dozens if not a hundred times in this procedure and in other spots in the database so I know it is not in that.  I also know that the above SQL works because it was working great for over a year and now when I run that statement the database hangs up.  There is no invalid data in the table which information is being deleted from, we checked for that first.  We also have tried compact and repair on the databases because we are worried this is a corruption in the data database though this does not rule that out and probably is what is going on.

Thank you for your help and let me know if you have questions to help you better understand this issue.

Comment: I assume you have tried a `SELECT` version of the data set you're trying to delete and successfully gotten that?  Also has the number of records dramatically changed in either table?

Comment: @ashareef yes I have, I am able to open the table as well and I can then delete a row or a selection of rows at a time.  Sorry that was important information that I should have added to the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately don't have a concrete *this* is whats wrong answer for you but I'm going to write out how I would approach debugging this. This may be super obvious and you've already tested but I'm a big proponent of double checking even the most trivial of things.  The reason to check the SQL even if it is unchanged isn't to check the validity of the SQL but to also identify if nothing has changed on the database end (e.g. large number of new records that makes the nested query too large which causes a timeout, tables being locked etc)

Check the query `SELECT [Run ID] FROM [SecondTableName] WHERE [Run ID] IS NOT NULL;` and make sure it returns what you expect.

Check the query `DELETE [TableName].* "FROM [TableName] WHERE [TableName].[Run ID] IN (<put in a test value>);`.  This probably involves a couple of test records

Check the query `DELETE [TableName].* "FROM [TableName] WHERE [TableName].[Run ID] NOT IN (<put in a test values>);`.  This probably involves either making a copy of the table and using that or add another conditional in the `WHERE` statement so you can use test records in your existing table.  Since it's in access I would just make the copy unless its prohibitively large.

After all this if you haven't found any issues, then I'm unfortunately out of ideas.